# Should I use mvvmcross for Xamarin.Forms and Windows Store app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I'm developing application for platforms:

- iOS (tablets & phones), Android (tablets & phones) & Windows Phone - Xamarin.Forms
- Windows Store - native for windows tablets.

Should I use mvvmCross? Or maybe there's a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is probably going to be closed due to being off topic for asking an opinion instead of specifically help with code. To give a quick answer, MvvmCross can do this and can do it pretty well. MvvmLight can do quite a bit of it, though they don't quite support bindings in iOS yet I believe, though they are adding it. Xamarin Forms supports binding on all platforms through xaml, so you may run into problems only when doing platform-specific code. The amount of this will vary based on your application.

Answer (score 1):

I pushed on Nuget my customizations of Cheesebaron FormsPresenters work.

It's an MvvmCross plugin called MvxForms (formally MvvmCross- Xamarin Forms plugin) and its 1.2.0-beta1 version avaible on pre-release nuget channel allows you to work with MvvmCross & Xamarin.Forms on iOS, Android, Windows Phone Silverlight, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 thanks to last Xamarin Forms pre version packages.

You should be good to go with Xamarin Forms & MvvmCross development on each platform, including Windows store.

- Blog post explaining use [here](https://mobilitips.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/use-mvvmcross-with-xamarin-forms-thanks-to-mvxforms-plugin/).
- Nuget description [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MobiliTips.MvxPlugins.MvxForms/1.2.0-beta1).
- GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/MobiliTips/MvxPlugins).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any standard MVVM approach, keep all ViewModel inside [PCL](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/) and this PCL can be referenced in Windows Store Native so all you business logic and view models, models are same for all the project you mentioned.

samples on Xamarin Forms MVVM:

- http://blog.falafel.com/learning-xamarin-mvvm-light-xamarin-forms/
- https://github.com/RobGibbens/DtoToVM